# MongoDB find documents if a property array doesn't contain an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of documents like this.

```
[
  {
     "name" : "test",
     "data" : [
         { "code" : "name", "value" : "Diego" },      
         { "code" : "nick", "value" : "Darko" },      
         { "code" : "special", "value" : true }
     ]
  },
  {
     "name" : "another",
     "data" : [
         { "code" : "name", "value" : "Antonio" },      
         { "code" : "nick", "value" : "Tony" }
     ]
  }
]
```

now I need to find all the documents that:

a) **don't contain a "data" item with code "special"**

OR

b) **contains a "data" item with code "special" and value false**

It's like I needed the opposite of **$elemMatch** or I'm missing something?

Comment: Why doesn't a simple {$ne:"special"} work for you against "data.code"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're inserting each document in your list of documents as a separate member of a collection `test`.

For a,

```
db.test.find({ "data.code" : { "$ne" : "special" } })
```

For b.,

```
db.test.find({ "data" : { "$elemMatch" : { "code" : "special", "value" : false } } })
```

Combining the two with `$or`,

```
db.test.find({ "$or" : [
    { "data.code" : { "$ne" : "special" } },
    { "data" : { "$elemMatch" : { "code" : "special", "value" : false } } }
] })
```

Comment: The $or combination helps me so much... Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Hope this **$ni**n will solve your issues.
I insertd your docs into "so" collection

> db.so.find({}).pretty();

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5489cd4f4cb16307b808d4b2"),
        "name" : "test",
        "data" : [
                { "code" : "name",
                  "value" : "Diego"
                },
                { "code" : "nick",
                  "value" : "Darko"
                },
                { "code" : "special",
                  "value" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5489cd674cb16307b808d4b3"),
        "name" : "another",
        "data" : [
                {"code" : "name",
                 "value" : "Antonio"
                },
                { "code" : "nick",
                  "value" : "Tony"
                }
        ]
}
```

**don't contain a "data" item with code "special"**

```
> db.so.find({"data.code":{$nin:["special"]}}).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5489cd674cb16307b808d4b3"),
        "name" : "another",
        "data" : [
                { "code" : "name",
                  "value" : "Antonio"
                },
                { "code" : "nick",
                  "value" : "Tony"
                }
        ]
}
```

**contains a "data" item with code "special" and value false**

> db.so.find({$and:[{"data.code":"special"},{"data.value":false}]}).pretty();